# Keep the session alive even if the browser closed

Tags: php, session, cookies

I got a problem when im trying to keep the session alive even if the browser is closed

When the user push 'Remember me' checkbox it will save the cookies

```
<input type='checkbox' name='me' value='r'>
```

Well, i have tried the following:

```
<?php
session_start ();
$_SESSION['key'] = 'myprivatekey';
if (!isset($_SESSION['key']){
   die ();
}else{
    if ($_POST['me'] == 'r'){
        setcookie(session_name (), session_id (), time()+11111111);
    }
}
echo 'passed';
```

Comment: This is not what im looking for

Comment: @JayBlanchard why you marked this as duplicate, i didn't get the answer yet

Comment: It is a duplicate because the answer is in the other post.

Comment: @JayBlanchard i didn't answer, i asked how to!

Comment: You asked how to and the duplicate contains the answer.

Comment: so its imposible to keep the session even if the browser is closed? there no way?

Comment: That is why they are called "Sessions".

Comment: @JayBlanchard can you please tell me how to solve that using setcookie(); sir?

Comment: Store the variables you need to store in the cookie then check for cookies each time a visitor comes to your site.

Comment: @JayBlanchard an example please, im newbie in php, sorry

Comment: Lots of examples everywhere - [start with the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)